# Will using a member initializer list make the initialization slightly faster?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

In his book "Programming, Principles and practices using C++" Bjarne Stroustrup introduces the concept of **member initializer list** on pages 314-316 (§ 9.4.4). He uses the following example:

```
// Simple Date (year, month, day)

class Date
{
public:
    Date(int yy, int mm, int dd): y{yy}, m{mm}, d{dd}
    {
        //...
    }

private:
    int y, m, d;
};
```

On page 315 he says:

> We could have written:
>
> ```
> Date::Date(int yy, int mm, int dd)  // constructor
> {
>     y = yy;
>     m = mm;
>     d = dd;
> }
> ```
>
> but then we would in principle first have default initialized the members and then assigned values to them.

Therefore, can I conclude that using **member initializer lists** makes the code slightly faster? Of course, no one would notice on a modern PC. But I'm planning to use C++ for embedded development.

EDIT:
I'll further specify my question. By "slightly faster" I actually mean "less CPU cycles involved".
I also agree that the potential efficiency increase for this particular example will be near to nothing. But for much larger classes and structs, it might become noticable on a microcontroller.

Comment: With `int`s? There wouldn't be any difference. Try with some heavy classes.

Comment: This is all optimized out if there are no side effects.

Comment: Make one member const. Which way is viable now? There's more than performance involved these decisions. Use a member initializer list as the default, always.

Comment: Your question kinda has an obvious answer. *"Will doing something in **one** non-vacuous phase be faster than **two** non-vacuous phases?"* Naturally, if the two phases are comparable in terms of instruction count, than cutting one out will conserve CPU cycles...

Comment: In many real-life cases, using the initialization list (or in-class initializers) *is* faster than using the constructor body. In *some* cases the compiler can optimize it all to the same thing (but don't count on it). Do use the initialization list when you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second example you are not initializing, you are assigning to variables which have been already initialized. The variables are initialized (default constructed) before entering the constructor, so you are actually setting them twice.

An `int` doesn't have any specific default initializer so you don't notice but try with different code [as in](https://ideone.com/u9GHv6)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
  int x;

public:
  Foo() : x(0) { cout << "Foo()" << endl; }
  Foo(int x) : x(x) { cout << "Foo(int)" << endl; }
  Foo& operator=(const Foo& o) { 
    cout << "Foo::operator=(const Foo&)" << endl; 
    this->x = o.x; return *this;
  }
};

class Bar
{
   Foo foo;
public:  
   Bar(const Foo& foo) { this->foo = foo; }
   Bar(bool, const Foo& foo) : foo(foo) { }
};

int main() {
  cout << "Assigned in constructor" << endl;
  Bar bar = Bar(Foo(5));
  cout << "Assigned in initializer list" << endl;
  Bar bar2 = Bar(false, Foo(5));
}
```

This prints

```
Assigned in constructor
Foo(int)
Foo()
Foo::operator=(const Foo&)
Assigned in initializer list
Foo(int)
```

so you see they're definitely not equivalent. Indeed, for example, you are not able to assign a `const` field in a constructor

Comment: Waw, interesting code snippet! So in your example: (1) The "Assigned in constructor" leads to 3 calls to the Foo constructor and (2) The "Assigned in initializer list" leads to only 1 call to the Foo constructor.

Comment: Those 3 calls to the Foo constructor => This means there are 3 Foo objects sitting somewhere in memory?

Comment: Actually to two calls of `Foo` constructor and a copy assignment operator, `Foo()` is invoked when `Bar` is constructed. Then `Foo(int)` is called to construct a temporary `Foo` which is passed by const reference to `operator=` of the `foo` contained in the `Bar` which copies the value. Then the temporary is destroyed. A member initializer list avoids this because it's a restricted place in which you initialize objects so the compiler is free to do whatever he wants. They're not just assignments in a block of code, as in a constructor.

Comment: Great! I just wonder why the 'const' is needed in your example. Would it work similarly without?

Comment: You say " `Foo()` is invoked when `Bar` is constructed. Then `Foo(int)` is called ... " But from the printout, it looks like `Foo(int)` is called first?

Comment: Yes `Foo(int)` is called first because arguments of a function/constructor are evaluated before calling the constructor of `Bar` which will initialize all members before entering its constructor code (and will use default initialization if you don't provide one in member initializer list).

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard specifies "default initialization" as follows:

> [dcl.init]
>
> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is
>   a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default
>   constructor (12.1) for T is called (and the initialization is
>   ill-formed if T has no default constructor or overload resolution
>   (13.3) results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or
>   inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
>
> — if T is an
>   array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Your class members are plain, garden-variety, `int`s. They are not classes. They are not arrays. Therefore default-initialization, in the case of `int`s, does nothing.

I will expect most compilers to generate identical code, in both of your examples. It makes no difference, whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik. Could you think of an example in which it does matter?

Comment: This is pointed out by the cite from the standard. If the class member itself is a (another) class, with a constructor that actually, well, does something, then it would matter.

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik :-)

Comment: It is still probably a better habit to use initializer lists.  If you study the subject there are things that can only be done with initializer lists.